# Pairwise Independence

Tags: statistics, random-variables, independence

Okay, so recently, I asked a question about two siblings who are playing $10$ rounds of a soccer/football game. James has a $70%$ chance of scoring each time and John has a $60%$ chance of scoring each time.

So last time, we modelled it as a random variable such that every scenario x, $x = (J_{A_1},J_{O_1},..., J_{A_{10}},J_{O_{10}})$. Now, I am trying to prove that they are pairwise independent. The issue is that I know the correct answers should be in the range of $\frac{42}{100}$ (which is for when they both score). But I don't know how to prove it. Any help please

[Part 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4816512/two-brothers-playing-on-a-saturday/4816556#4816556)